# Using FindResource() with a memory buffer instead of a file

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I'm trying to compile some png's into a RES file, which then will be compressed with zlib. In my main program, I want to decompress the RES file, store it in memory, and start using resources compiled within it. Normally I would use

```
FindResource(NULL, ...);
```

to find a resource embedded in my .exe file. But now the resource file resides in a memory buffer, to which the pointer I have. Is it possible to use FindResource with such a pointer, or does it work only with files?

Comment: Not that this is necessarily helpful, but would it be a tremendous reach to suggest zlib'ing the png before putting it in the resource file, then keeping the resource file as-is ? Minus the .res overhead (which isn't much) it would seem a reasonable alternative. What you want may be doable sans-memory mapping a file, but off the top of my head I can't recall if it is indeed straightforward. sry.

Comment: Well, that could certainly be an alternative, and I will probably use this approach. Still, it would be nice to know if it's somehow possible to use the memory.

Comment: yeah I'm a little curious myself. I'll keep a watch on this as well. best of luck. if I run across something i'll post back.

Comment: PNGs are already compressed - what do you think you'll gain from compressing them again? Just make them normal resources in your .exe.

Comment: That's true. So what would be the right solution for storing HD pictures in some kind of a resource file? JPG and PNG are compressed, so zlib won't do much. One can compile a resource file and use it as a seperate file, instead of linking it with the .exe, so that it doesn't seem unnaturally big. Is there another, commonly known solution?